# font looks different in windows compared to mac

Tags: bootstrap-4

The problem that I am facing is that text in bootstrap looks very different on windows compared to mac. On windows it looks like regular large font. Meanwhile, on mac and my iPhone it looks deeper and slightly bolded. This problem is everywhere on my app. How can I have the mac and iPhone look on the windows platform?

Examples:

[text-example-windows-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4im4d.png) vs [text-example-mac-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ilz.png)

[text-example-windows-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjqxb.png) vs [text-example-mac-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5pkC.png)

I am on the latest bootstrap 4.5. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure there is a problem here. Things will look different on different platforms/browsers/etc...If UI problem arises that don't just 'look different', then there are ways to narrow down and correct the issue in css/js/whatever else. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably is that in mac the font used in windows is not installed. This is normal and thats why always you have to put more than one font. One solution is to add the google fonts cdn of the font you wish to use. It would take no more than 50kb i guess so, is worth it!.

Comment: I do have this on my application.html.erb. Do I need to do anything else? <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Check the browser console if the font are being loaded. Also, check if you are including the font in the bootstrap.scss